# One click install mongodb with WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb, visual-studio, deployment

I am trying to deploy a WPF Project that uses MongoDB. I want to create a One-Click installation system for the client who does not have any idea about computers. I tried creating a batch file but the best it does is, it starts the MongoDB setup file. Is there any possible way, I can install MongoDB without using their installer and bundle it with my deployed project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install mongoDB unattended on Windows.

Just use the **msi** installer like this

```
msiexec.exe /l*v mdbinstall.log  /qb /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.9-signed.msi
```

For more details check out their official documentation on this regard [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows-unattended/)